# Deleting Same Text at the Beginning of Every Post

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

I'm importing an RSS feed into WordPress using the WPAllImport plugin and dividing it into posts. The content section of each post contains the same graphic and title at the beginning. I want to eliminate this bit from each post so it doesn't display. I don't know if I can do this with the plugin or in how I display the content in the template.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems have you run into?

Answer (score 0):

The [search and replace](http://wp-cli.org/commands/search-replace/) command in [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org/) is perfect for this sort of thing, if you have access to the command line on either your development or live site.

Or there's a [search and replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/) plugin you could try.

Take a backup of your database first before using either of these.

If you want to leave the original posts intact, in case you change your mind later, you could use the [the_content](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) filter, and you'd need to use PHP's [preg_replace](http://php.net/preg_replace) command to swap out the text when the posts are displayed.